# Not getting a correct height for bounds of iphone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am having trouble setting up the frame for one of my views. I know that the height in points  of the iPhone 5 is 568, but when I enter this code into the `viewDidLoad` in my ViewController:

```
    var height = self.bounds.height
    println(height)
```

output:

```
    640.0
```

Why does it come out as this when it should be 568? Is it a problem with the simulator?

Comment: try self.view.bounds.height instead

Comment: And I think you have to put that code in viewWillAppear since the frame of the view isn't updated until then.

Comment: Whoops, I meant self.view.bounds.size.height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thin your viewController height is more than `568`.You have did `FreeForm`.Check the height in `Size inspector` of your view controller.
Make `simulated size` `fixed`.

[image]

**EDIT:** You can make it `portrait` and `iPhone 4 inch` to show it correctly see below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the height of the screen you want the height of the VIEW. To do that you would want:

DO NOT PUT:

`var height = self.view.bounds.height`

DO:

`var height = self.view.bounds.size.height`

Comment: What are you getting as height?

Comment: @heinzelmanB Take the suggestion from my second comment underneath your post

Comment: @LyndseyScott no, it should be fine in the viewDidLoad. I ran my example code on the iPhone 4 simulator and got 480.

Comment: Did you change it to self.view.bounds.size.height -- Instead of self.view.bounds.height

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with my simulator if you got it right. @WyattMufson